# How to send artifacts from github actions to azure windows VM

Tags: github-actions, continuous-deployment, azure-virtual-machine, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, artifacts

I have build my project with GitHub actions pipeline running on windows agent. The artifacts are generated and stored in the repo. The next task of mine is to send it to the azure windows VM. I really don't know how to do this. Anyone can please help me.

```
name: Deploy to Azure Windows VM

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - do/cs

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-2019

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

And continue this pipeline to build my C# project. Now the artifacts are downloaded in the repo, I am wishing to send it to AZURE windows VM. Here is the action I am using:

```
     - name: Copy artifacts to azure VM 
       uses: azure/scp-action@v2
        with:
         host: 'VM-public-ip' 
          username: 'azureuser'
          password: 'pwsd' 
          source:  ./test.zip 
          target: 'C:\\Users\a\zureuser\\'
```

Where **test.zip** are the artifacts downloaded into the repo.

Kindly continue this pipeline and deploy my artifacts to windows VM. Assume that we have artifacts by the name of test.zip. I have build my project but cannot make it happen to deploy to azure windows VM.
Kindly help me. Thanks

Anyone please help:)

Comment: I'm not familiar a lot with the Azure VMs, but maybe this Action can help - https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-azure-virtual-machine-image

Comment: That action is to *build* a virtual machine, not push artifacts. As for the deploy, it's unclear what you are trying to deploy. There are dozens of way to deploy things to a VM but without knowing what your end state or goal is, it be extremely difficult to get you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti I do have artifacts of C#. I want to push these to Azure VM.

Comment: The azure/scp-action action is used to securely copy the artefacts to the Azure Windows VM. You'll need to provide the public IP address of the Azure Windows VM, a valid username and password to access the VM, the source file (./test.zip) which is the artefacts downloaded into the repo, and the target directory (C:\\Users\azureuser\\) on the Azure Windows VM where the artefacts should be copied to.

After copying the artefacts, you can add additional steps to unzip the artefacts and install them on the Azure Windows VM, as required by your deployment process.